# How to search for similar words in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, freetext, containstable

I am using `CONTAINS` and `FREETEXT` on SQL query to search for text in big text fields.

What I noticed that the search returns result when the exact word match, but what if I want to search for similar words?

For example, when I type **Carlo**, it did not display anything if what I have is **Carlos** (with an **S**)

Below is a simple query similar to the one I use:

```
SELECT P.*                      
FROM MyTable AS P
WHERE(CONTAINS(P.*, 'Carlo') OR freetext(P.*, 'Carlo'))
```

How can I make the search bring similar words to **Carlo** such as **Carlos**, **Carla**, etc... without affecting the performance?

Comment: You might take a look at SOUNDEX. Of course it will affect the performance to some extent because you are changing the query. By definition that can affect performance.

Comment: How do you intend to use this? SOUNDEX won't help if you want to find words that differ by 1 or 2 letters, eg to correct name spelling or implement a `Did you mean?` feature. SQL Server's FTS is like Google, it searches for a word, its derivatives, synonyms etc. To perform fuzzy matching you need different algorithms

Comment: Thank you! I think SOUNDEX won't help in this case

Comment: you might have some luck using an inflectional form: `WHERE CONTAINS (P.*, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "Carlo")') `

Comment: To find eg names that differ by only one character or one transposition you need to calculate the Damerau-Levenshtein distance betweem the input and all the target data. This isn't available in SQL Server nor can it be accelerated by indexes. There are algorithms that can accelerate this in code. If you don't have too much data, you could load all and process all the data in memory to accelerate fuzzy matching lookups

Comment: @AhmedAli if you have a *lot* of data, you should consider using ElasticSearch which creates an index to accelerate string distance calculations.

Comment: @AhmedAli for small to medium sizes you can precalculate all 1 letter variations of a word and save it in a table. Do the same for the input and search for matches. This will return all words that differ by 1 or 2 letters from the input. The upside is that you can index the variations. The downside is that this takes a LOT of space

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to find synonyms (thesaurus lookup, like with `FREETEXT`)?  Similar-sounding words (`SOUNDEX`)?  Misspellings?  In the above, "Carlo" and "Carla" probably don't fit any of the tools (assuming they're proper names).  Each is a different task, requiring different algorithms.  If you clarify what you're looking for, we may be able to help more.

Comment: @AhmedAli this question is like asking for a screwdriver to turn a screw because the hammer failed. Unless you tell us what type of screw it is, we can't tell you what screwdriver to use - slot, cross, square, hex ?

Comment: You are not going to get a fuzzy search without effecting performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT P.*                      
FROM MyTable AS P
WHERE CONTAINS(P.*, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "Carlo")')
```

For reference you can check [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142566(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look and I will get back to you

Comment: @AhmedAli you have to explain *what* you want to do first. Full text search is different from fuzzy matching or finding similarly *sounding* names. Different algorithms, different tradeoffs. `Carlos` and `Carla` clearly aren't inflectional forms of one another. One could be a misspelling of the other though

Comment: I wanted the full text search because it is faster, then I noticed that full text search doesn't bring the details as fuzzy matching, so I am looking for the possibility to use both at once

Comment: By the way `'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, Carlo)'` did not work

Comment: @AhmedAli fuzzy matching is not the same as full text search. What do you want to use fuzzy matching *for*? How much data is there?

Comment: enclose Carlo in double quotes " "

Comment: @ArslanudDinShafiq this isn't about quotes. Carlos and Carla are NOT inflectional forms of each other. They are different *names* that happen to differ by 2 letters. You can't use FTS algorithms for fuzzy string matching

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP's is sounding a lot like an XY problem, and we're all flailing in the dark trying to figure out what OP is looking for.  If the language at issue is English, then Carlos and Carla are not inflectional forms, as you said.  It doesn't sound to me like even OP has defined his problem yet (two proper names are not synonyms, they're statically arbitrary, so `FREETEXT` is not remotely applicable.)

Comment: I understand this, which is why I mentioned multiple possibilities in the question comments. It's impossible to give a better answer right now